# Escaping string for MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following select statement:

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from Table where Name='{$_REQUEST['name']}'");
```

However, since this kind of query is prone to SQL injection, I am using a more secured way for the selection:

```
$escaped_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
$res = mysql_query("select * from Table where Name='{$escaped_name}'");
```

It all works fine until I try to run the selection with a `$_REQUEST['name']` that contains the string `Joel's` .In that case the selection doesn't work. After debugging and printing the content of `$escaped_name` to the screen, I got the following:

```
Joel\\\'s
```

What is the reason for this? It seems like the string was escaped automatically, and then I escaped it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data was probably auto-escaped by PHP's (deprecated) "[magic quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)" feature. To disable magic quotes in .htaccess:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
```

Comment: +1! Note that you can disable this in your php.ini, too (of course).

Answer (score 2):

You've run into an issue in PHP caused by a "feature" called Magic Quotes.  PHP attempts to escape strings when Magic Quotes is enabled, but as different databases have different escaping schemes, the results can be pretty useless, or even dangerous.

There are two possible solutions.  the simplest, and recommended solution is to just turn magic quotes off in php.ini or .htaccess.

The second approach is to use magic_quotes_gpc to test if the feature is enabled, then running stripslashes on your input if it is.  Then run mysql_real_escape_string on the result.

Comment: Sounds tempting to turn it off, but if you somehow forget to escape a string before running a query, this seems to be a good fallback.. thanks!

Comment: It's not really a good fallback. It's not reliable cross-database and cross-charset, and it'll mangle strings you *do* remember to escape/parameterise or which you use in contexts other than SQL. It's a broken mess, and it's going away in a future PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "run the selection" but i would guess from what you're saying that you have magic quotes turned on.

If you dont have access to the php.ini either check `phpinfo()` or add this to a file:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  echo "on";
}else{
  echo "off";
}
```

If they are turned on they can be disabled in various places such as php.ini or .htaccess files

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is by using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) which avoids escaping. The automatic escaping is caused by [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) and can be disabled using [these methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

An instant solution (assuming you leave magic quotes enabled) would be:

`mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']));`